# Is "insurmountable by" correct?

Tags: grammar

I found this sentence.

> "We rolled on toward the island, insurmountable by the inclement weather."
>   -- Jerry M Keene

Is this "insurmountable by" correct here?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: The inclement weather makes the island insurmountable.

Comment: @J.R. Do you not see/hear the awkwardness? In normal conversation, I would expect "We rolled on toward the island, *which was* insurmountable by the inclement weather," or some other connecting words.

Comment: That comment you just made: "In normal conversation, I would expect _We rolled on toward the island, which was insurmountable by the inclement weather_," should be part of your question. Otherwise, it's hard for us to figure out where you think the problem might me.

Comment: It would be correct as "... the island, *made* insurmountable by the inclement weather." Otherwise it sounds, nonsensically, as though the island is insurmountable to the weather, not to the speaker.

Answer (score 1):

Other than taking a lot of poetic license, it's fine.

One implication is that the island has one or more very high peaks that are untouched by weather.

Another is simply the writers determination to reach the island is insurmountable.